# What are the differences between a standard Merlin engine and the Merlin Vacuum engine?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engines, merlin-1d

I know that there's a difference between SpaceX's Falcon 9 1st stage engines and the 2nd stage engine, since that stage is specifically tuned for vacuum. Wikipedia also says that the Merlin Vacuum Engine is larger than the standard Merlin 1D. That got me thinking... are there more differences?

What are the differences between the first stage Merlin engines and the second stage Merlin vacuum engine? (I'm especially interested in size comparison, efficiency, thrust, etc.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The biggest difference is the [nozzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine_nozzle). For optimal performance in vacuum, you want a much larger one.

According to [Spaceflight 101](http://www.spaceflight101.com/falcon-9-v11.html), the chamber pressure is the same, but the expansion ratio (throat area to end-of-nozzle area) is 7 times larger in the vacuum variant, which (if correct) implies about 2.7 times the nozzle diameter if the throat is unchanged.

The Wikipedia description of the [1C-vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)#Merlin_Vacuum_.281C.29) says the expansion nozzle length is 2.7 meters, while the overall length of the first-stage 1C is only 2.9 meters long - roughly half of that being nozzle. So the nozzle length is basically doubled. Presumably the relationship between the 1D and 1D vacuum is analogous.

This pic is said to be, left to right: Falcon 1 Merlin 1C, Falcon 9 1C (different mounting), and Falcon 9 2nd stage 1C vacuum -- *without* the extension nozzle, so it's a shorter, fatter nozzle than the others.

[image: 2 Merlin 1Cs and a 1C-vacuum]

And here's what the extension nozzle looks like by itself:
[image]

Since the Falcon 9 second stage mounts a single engine, in the same diameter body as the first stage (with its cluster of 9), there's plenty of room for the large nozzle.

This [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/2ww1ci/the_100th_merlin_1d_rocket_engine_helped_launch/) includes some inconclusive debate about how much different the vacuum engines actually are. There are certainly differences in mounting and layout (most obviously the gas generator exhaust nozzle is canted further out to avoid impinging on the nozzle extension), but the turbopumps etc. are apparently the same.

According to the [October 2015 revision of the Falcon 9 user's guide](http://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf), the 1D Vacuum has a much deeper throttling capability than the first-stage engine, down to about 40% of maximum thrust (360kN-934kN). It's unclear what the reason for the throttling difference is; it could be that the engine is susceptible to exhaust flow separation at low thrust settings into high ambient air pressure.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprised at just how *much* bigger the vacuum engine is. I'll wait to accept just in case there's other answers, but once again, great answer.

Comment: Yeah, vacuum-optimized nozzles can be startlingly large. The Apollo service module propulsion system is a good example; given its size proportional to the spacecraft you might think the engine should produce more than 0.3g.

Comment: The vacuum nozzle extension is a thin shell (1/64" at the bottom) that has no active cooling system. The non-vacuum nozzle has much thicker walls with channels attached, fuel flows through the channels to cool the nozzle.

Comment: ...and while in atmospheric flight, past early stage of dense atmosphere (first 10km or so) the large nozzle would benefit engine performance, first the big bell would create extra air drag, and besides there's simply no room for nozzles that big on the 9 tightly packed engines.

Comment: Would a question about why larger nozzles work better in vacuums be appropriate? That sounds absolutely interesting.

Comment: The expansion of the nozzle reduces the pressure of the exhaust, and performance is best when the pressure at the end of the nozzle matches the ambient (external) pressure. In vac, you'd like an infinitely large nozzle to get the exit pressure to zero, but that's impractical...

Comment: Throttling an engine causes a severe drop in chamber pressure. With supersonic flight through the atmosphere, the air turbulence could cause combustion instabilities by disturbing the flow of exhaust gases  under lower pressure. A vacuum engine can afford much lower pressures, and low thrust is good for precision maneuvers. The landing engine would benefit from the lower throttle too, but flying nozzle-first into the wind it can't really afford having ambient air pumped into the combustion chamber against the exhaust.

Comment: @SF. The landing doesn’t want a lower throttle; that wastes fuel.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: The landing without lower throttle often wastes the rocket. It would definitely want a lower throttle if it means enough time to maneuver and settle on the drone ship instead of either crashing into the sea or launching back up. Currently it can't throttle below TWR 1, the entire hover-slam procedure very precarious and leaving very little room for corrections. Sure brake at full throttle, but the very touchdown could definitely benefit from more precise control.

Answer (score 7):

There are several reasons for having deep throttling in the vacuum engine but not the first stage engine.

(1) The first stage cannot use a large expansion bell, and couldn't even if the mechanicals allowed it, because the exhaust flow would separate from the bell. This would cause flow instability/backflow/... that would likely destroy or damage the bell, or worse. Any rocket bell's outflow pressure should match the ambient atmospheric pressure for maximum efficiency. (This does mean that any traditional rocket nozzle with best efficiency at sea level is less efficient at all higher altitudes.)

(2) The first stage only needs to throttle down slightly near the end of its burn to limit payload acceleration to five or six g (I forget... 6 I think). Even without throttling, this could be accomplished by shutting down engines.

(3) The second stage needs to throttle down much more and earlier (percentage-wise; the burn is considerably longer) to limit payload g forces. For lighter payloads, it has to throttle down even more and earlier. Because the engine is firing in empty space, there's no limit to the size of the nozzle or concern about flow separation.

Comment: This appears to be an extended comment to another answer, not a reply to this question. You may be able to [edit] so it can stand on its own.

Comment: Yes doesn't have any stats or fact. 
Also payload speed should be in velocity not acceleration (Ex m/s or km/s rather than m/s2).

Answer (score 1):

The main object of any rocket engine is to give the highest impulse to the
rocket. mv(rocket)=mv(fuel) so for a given mass of fuel you want the maximum
velocity possible. The larger nozzle divergence bell makes the better use
of the vacuum to reach the highest possible velocity.